# Cannot change ownership of partition

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, ext4, chmod

I've been trying to change ownership of an ext4 partition but it just won't work, telling me there's no such file or directory.

Here's the relevant output of `lsblk`

```
 └─sda2 8:2 0 411,7G 0 part /media/jonas/483ad320-0a82-476a-813f-e49ed6034
```

I can't seem to create folders on it, and gparted shows the mount point as `/`. However, when running

```
sudo chown $USER /media/jonas/483ad320-0a82-476a-813f-e49ed6034
```

It says there's no such file or directory.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Should probably mention that the drive doesn't seem to show up in `fstab`, and also that that file doesn't look right at all...

Answer (score 0):

So I seem to have made an error (though I followed guides to the tee). Either I typed in the path wrong multiple times (and copypasted it wrong) or I made a formatting error... anyway.
The code that solved it was:

```
sudo chown -R $JONAS:$JONAS /media/jonas/483ad320-0a82-476a-813e-e49ed6034def
```

Before that, the `-R` was used at the end, but that doesn't explain that the media wasn't found. Oh well...